# Display “&” from text file

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to display some text from a .txt file in a label, but the text has an ampersand in it which will not display. I am getting the text by reading singles lines using a `System.IO.StreamReader`. I tried using a backslash as an escape character, but all that did was display a backslash in the label.

Comment: You need to double it, &&.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another & as an escape character.

`&&`

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sr As New StreamReader("C:\yada.txt")
Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine
Label1.Text = line.Replace("&", "&&")
```